# Read value from json string by string operation

Tags: c#, json, string, string-operations

How to read "key" and "key1"'s value from below string.
Its json but I can not parse as its very large number and its broke while parsing.

so, would like to read the somelongnumber and somelongnumber2 through string operation.

```
{key:somelongnumber,key1:somelongnumber2}
```

which would be the easiest way to get this value.

string with data:

```
{key:987680907568874555505607487995865555765995697489705794879988794489875875748987900769748746885877550977678595976099650577885777777684698859955669967959569775575067,key1:57069588960687005850750777094807006847879887980496989949579940779055857509947777847575786087598684799568577408880997966575750505586786988505685776878966949595807557508787784690576899698976897568855509907577566780999748589995405946407480098700854777748707067084789808075807709656084406888907505699899840957887847487008975787755684857507580057597799985874870997758507505954704880888999859760585587860777649885965487088048678878505979799046569808657874800555897997680907568874805607487995865555765995697489705794879988794489875875748987900769748746885877550977678455976099650577885777777684698859955669967959569775575067}
```

Comment: how did it brake? could it fit in a long?

Comment: Don´t parse JSON by hand, use a JSON-parser.

Comment: JSON numbers are double precision IEEE 754 numbers, so they can't be _that_ large or it wouldn't be valid JSON anyway. If what you mean is that they're actually strings, then that's a different problem.

Comment: I tried with JSON.Parse and JsonConvert.deserializedObject both are failed. so, looking by string operation way.

Comment: Post an example of the real JSON you're trying to parse, I want to know if those numbers are strings or not in the file.

Comment: edited with example.

Comment: Yes, its the data request received and which can have different values each time. Just want to parse to string.

Comment: Any easiest way to do string operation to read these two keys ?

Comment: @user3711357 You can just strip the curly braces with `Trim` split on comma with `Split`, then split on the semi-colon and you'll have the name and value.

Comment: No quotes on the keys. That looks more like a JS object...

Comment: That's not valid JSON, in any case. There needs to be quotes around that number, and that key.

Comment: exactly as Etienne told : it's not valid JSON. Thus, you can't use a simple JSON parser here. But a small manipulation to add quotes to the key and the value of the example data doesn't seem too hard to do.

Comment: Thanks for all comments. finally, I communicated further to provide with quotes (in string form instead of long number).

Answer (score 1):

Here is your class for deserializing

```
class JsonClass
{
    public System.Numerics.BigInteger Key1 {get; set;}
    public System.Numerics.BigInteger Key2 {get; set;}
}
```

For deserializing

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(inputJson);
Console.WriteLine(result.Key1);
```

Comment: I want to convert to string. and tried with string, its not working.

Comment: Obvioulsy OPs problem is the huge number, not using JsonConvert, making your anser a no-answer.

Comment: its not work. this says error as , "is not a valid number." that's why looking for string operation.

Comment: can you try with `System.Numerics.BigInteger`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really want to deal with JSON serialization and DTO's and your only objective is to parse this input, you can try with something like this:

```
string myData = "YOUR JSON INPUT";
string[] mydata2 = myData.Trim('{').Trim('}').Split(',');
string firstVal = mydata2[0].Split(':')[1];
string secondVal = mydata2[1].Split(':')[1];
```

Although if you want a long term solution, better keep with JSON serialization.